# 2sxc | Export App Error

Tags: 2sxc

When I export my 2sxc Content App from my site I am seeing the following error:

> (function(){var c=0;if("undefined"!==typeof
>   CustomEvent&&"function"===typeof window.dispatchEvent){var
>   a=function(a){try{if("object"===typeof
>   a&&(a=JSON.stringify(a)),"string"===typeof a)return
>   window.dispatchEvent(new
>   CustomEvent("lprequeststart",{detail:{data:a,requestID:++c}})),c}catch(f){}},b=function(a){try{window.dispatchEvent(new
>   CustomEvent("lprequestend",{detail:a}))}catch(f){}};"undefined"!==typeof
>   XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send&&(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send=
>   function(c){return function(f){var
>   d=this,e=a(f);e&&d.addEventListener("loadend",function(){b({requestID:e,statusCode:d.status})});return
>   c.apply(d,arguments)}}(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send));"function"===typeof
>   fetch&&(fetch=function(c){return function(f,d){var
>   e=a(d),g=c.apply(this,arguments);if(e){var
>   h=function(a){b({requestID:e,statusCode:a&&a.status})};g.then(h)"catch"}return
>   g}}(fetch))}})(); (function(){if("undefined"!==typeof CustomEvent){var
>   c=function(a){if(a.lpsubmit)return a;var
>   b=function(){try{this.dispatchEvent(new
>   CustomEvent("lpsubmit"))}catch(k){}return
>   a.apply(this,arguments)};b.lpsubmit=!0;return
>   b};window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){if(document&&document.forms&&0

I'm trying to export from one dnn site to another (I've already successfully exported the pages that these content apps are placed on). I see the following on my new site when using dnn site wizard to export all content and files:

> Error: System.Exception: Data is missing - usually when a site is
>   copied but the content / apps have not been imported yet - check
>   2sxc.org/help?tag=export-import

Comment: I don't have a quick answer, and for more than that your question isn't detailed enough. Maybe a quick video or something?

Comment: I was able to successfully export the content as an xml file in 'parts' from each app and then re import these parts to my new site (once I re installed each app again). The error message above appeared initially when I tried to export the entire app (as opposed to parts of an app). I am happy to export in parts so for now my requirements are met but still have not been able to export an entire app for re import. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you ran into was that you didn't check the "Include all Content-Groups" checkbox: 
[image]

Comment: Sry for delay in response....

I tested both with that 'Include all...' option selected and not selected with same result.

Same problem persists (although not always with a visible error message). I tested out a fresh install and everything exported fine. 

I think maybe its because I'm exporting quite a large amount of entities and files (2086, 179) that is causing the failed export.